# how to remove a specific factor level to missing value in r?

Tags: r, r-factor

I got a factor data set `df` that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(attend = c("yes", "no", "no", "iap", "yes", "yes", "iap"),
           sex = c("male", "female", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female"))

df$attend <- as.factor(df$attend)
df$sex <- as.factor(df$sex)

df
```

| attend | sex |
| --- | --- |
| yes | male |
| no | female |
| no | female |
| iap | male |
| yes | female |
| yes | male |
| iap | female |

I want to remove only the `iap` level from the `attend` variable.(I don't want to remove the entire row, what I'm looking for is to remove the level `iap`, so that it becomes a missing value under variable `attend`)

I tried the below code to remove it but it occurs an error saying:
Error in UseMethod("droplevels") :
no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "character".

```
df$attend <- droplevels(levels(df$attend)[4])
```

Much appreciated it if someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `levels` of the variable -

```
levels(df$attend)[levels(df$attend) == 'iap'] <- NA
df

#  attend    sex
#1    yes   male
#2     no female
#3     no female
#4   <NA>   male
#5    yes female
#6    yes   male
#7   <NA> female
```

This will also automatically drop the `'iap'` as level.

```
levels(df$attend)
#[1] "no"  "yes"
```

---

Here we can also use `forcats::fct_recode` to turn specific values to `NA`.

```
df$attend <- forcats::fct_recode(df$attend, NULL = 'iap')
```

Answer (score 3):

Another base R solution would be using `exclude`:

```
df$attend <- factor(df$attend, exclude = "iap")
```

```
  attend    sex
1    yes   male
2     no female
3     no female
4   <NA>   male
5    yes female
6    yes   male
7   <NA> female
```